# PRESTIGIO tablet and NTFS pendrive

Tags: android, ntfs

As far as I know, Android doesn't support NTFS file format, but when I connect pendrive with NTFS to my tablet (PRESTIGIO MULTIPAD 4 QUANTUM 7.85) it opens it with no problem and I can use files on it. Any ideas why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

NTFS is a File System and Linux (the underlying os on Android) does have NTFS support, it just depends if it is included in the kernel.

Prestigio in this example decided to include it in the build, so NTFS is supported in your device, but they are not the only ones that do so.